# Некорректная работа калькулятора цен на javascript

Tags: javascript

Прошу помощи.
Сделал вот такой калькулятор цен по выбранным товарам. Принцип такой - выбираешь модель товара и его кол-во. Жмешь на кнопку - добавить - и эта позиция с кол-вом автоматически создается ниже. можно создать сколько угодно позиций. Соответственно меняется итоговая сумма. И так же можно удалить любую позицию, с уменьшением итоговой суммы, на цену удаленного товара.
Проблема в том, что когда удаляешь самую последнюю позицию то все ок. Но если удаляешь позицию из середины или самую первую, то цена этой позиции дублируется столько раз, сколько есть еще позиций ниже удаляемой. Соответственно идет некорректное вычитание из итоговой суммы.
Мне кажется что дело в массиве(или правильно, нав., псевдомассиве), в который я беру кнопки удаления. Но в чем конкретно загвоздка не могу понять. Я перебираю через for of. Через forEach вообще не работает.
Буду признателен за любую помощь или подсказку

```js
let mainPrice = document.querySelector('.price__input'); // итоговая цена
let create = document.querySelector('.wrap-item'); // общий блок с элементами
let chooseModel = create.querySelector('.model'); // поле выбора модели
let chooseQuantity = create.querySelector('.values'); // поле выбора кол-ва 
let more = document.querySelector('.more-item'); // кнопка добавить позицию
let boxItems = document.querySelector('.box'); // блок, куда генерятся созданные позиции

more.addEventListener('click', function(){
  
  let selectVal = chooseModel.selectedIndex; // индекс выбранного option
  let allOptions = chooseModel.options; // все option в select
  let currOption = allOptions[selectVal]; // конкретная выбранная позиция
  let chooseModelPrice = currOption.getAttribute('data-price'); // сумма, которая стоит data-price
  let chooseModelValue = chooseModel.value; // выбранная модель
  
  // итоговая цена = итоговая цена + сумма, которая стоит в data-price * кол-во выбранной модели
  mainPrice.value = +mainPrice.value + chooseModelPrice * chooseQuantity.value;
  
  // создаем блок с полями (модель и кол-во)
  let item = document.createElement('div');
  item.classList.add('item');
  
  // создаем поле с выбранной моделью
  let addModel = document.createElement('input');
  addModel.classList.add('add-model');
  addModel.value = chooseModelValue;
  
  // создаем поле с выбранным кол-вом
  let addValues = document.createElement('input');
  addValues.classList.add('add-values');
  addValues.value = chooseQuantity.value;
  
  // создаем поле с суммой за конкретное кол-во выбранной модели
  let price = document.createElement('span');
  price.classList.add('curr-price');
  price.innerHTML = chooseModelPrice * chooseQuantity.value;
  
  // создаем кнопку, при клике на кот. будет удаляться соответствующий блок с полями
  let deleteItem = document.createElement('span');
  deleteItem.classList.add('delete-item');
  
  // добавляем все созданные элементы
  boxItems.appendChild(item);
  item.append(addModel, addValues, price, deleteItem);
  
  // сбрасываем значения полей выбора
  chooseModel.value = "Выберите модель";
  chooseQuantity.value = 1;
  
  deleteFunc();
});

// удаление позиций
let deleteBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('delete-item');
function deleteFunc(){
  for(let elem of deleteBtns){
    let currPrice = elem.parentElement.querySelector('.curr-price').innerHTML;
    elem.addEventListener('click', function(event){
      console.log(elem.parentElement);
      elem.parentElement.remove();
      mainPrice.value = mainPrice.value - currPrice;
    });
  }
}
```

```css
.form {
  width: 580px;
}
.form__item {
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0 0 30px 0;
}
.form__item label {
  display: block;
}
.form__submit {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrap-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.more-item {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.delete-item {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.delete-item::after {
  content: "-";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<form id="form" class="form" action="">

  <div class="wrap-item">
      <div class="form__item">
        <label for="">Модель</label>
        <select class="model" name="">
          <option>Выберите модель</option>
          <option value="Модель 1" data-price="100">Модель 1</option>
          <option value="Модель 2" data-price="200">Модель 2</option>
          <option value="Модель 3" data-price="300">Модель 3</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form__item">
        <label for="">Количество</label>
        <input type="number" class="form__input values" value="1" min="1">
      </div>
      <div class="form__item">
         <div class="more-item">Добавить позицию</div>
      </div>
 </div>
  <div class="box">

  </div>
<!--  ==========================  -->

<!--  ==========================  -->
  <div class="form__submit">
    <div class="form__price price">
      Итого:
      <input type="text" class="price__input" value="0">
      руб.
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не много изменил ваш код js, надеюсь он вам поможет. Работает сейчас так как вы просили. У вас зачем-то во время добавления новой позиции, в цикле перебирался eventListener. Я изменил его передав нужные параметры.

```js
let mainPrice = document.querySelector('.price__input'); // итоговая цена
let create = document.querySelector('.wrap-item'); // общий блок с элементами
let chooseModel = create.querySelector('.model'); // поле выбора модели
let chooseQuantity = create.querySelector('.values'); // поле выбора кол-ва 
let more = document.querySelector('.more-item'); // кнопка добавить позицию
let boxItems = document.querySelector('.box'); // блок, куда генерятся созданные позиции

more.addEventListener('click', function(){
  
  let selectVal = chooseModel.selectedIndex; // индекс выбранного option
  let allOptions = chooseModel.options; // все option в select
  let currOption = allOptions[selectVal]; // конкретная выбранная позиция
  let chooseModelPrice = currOption.getAttribute('data-price'); // сумма, которая стоит data-price
  let chooseModelValue = chooseModel.value; // выбранная модель
  
  // итоговая цена = итоговая цена + сумма, которая стоит в data-price * кол-во выбранной модели
  mainPrice.value = +mainPrice.value + chooseModelPrice * chooseQuantity.value;
  
  // создаем блок с полями (модель и кол-во)
  let item = document.createElement('div');
  item.classList.add('item');
  
  // создаем поле с выбранной моделью
  let addModel = document.createElement('input');
  addModel.classList.add('add-model');
  addModel.value = chooseModelValue;
  
  // создаем поле с выбранным кол-вом
  let addValues = document.createElement('input');
  addValues.classList.add('add-values');
  addValues.value = chooseQuantity.value;
  
  // создаем поле с суммой за конкретное кол-во выбранной модели
  let price = document.createElement('span');
  price.classList.add('curr-price');
  price.innerHTML = chooseModelPrice * chooseQuantity.value;
  
  // создаем кнопку, при клике на кот. будет удаляться соответствующий блок с полями
  let deleteItem = document.createElement('span');
  deleteItem.classList.add('delete-item');
  
  // добавляем все созданные элементы
  boxItems.appendChild(item);
  item.append(addModel, addValues, price, deleteItem);
  
  // сбрасываем значения полей выбора
  chooseModel.value = "Выберите модель";
  chooseQuantity.value = 1;
  
  deleteFunc(boxItems, item, deleteItem);
});

// удаление позиций
let deleteBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('delete-item');
function deleteFunc(parentElement, item, deleteItem){
    let currPrice = item.querySelector('.curr-price').innerHTML;
    deleteItem.addEventListener('click', function(event){
      console.log(item.parentElement);
      parentElement.removeChild(item);
      mainPrice.value = mainPrice.value - currPrice;
    });      
}
```

```css
.form {
  width: 580px;
}
.form__item {
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0 0 30px 0;
}
.form__item label {
  display: block;
}
.form__submit {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrap-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.more-item {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.delete-item {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.delete-item::after {
  content: "-";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<form id="form" class="form" action="">

  <div class="wrap-item">
      <div class="form__item">
        <label for="">Модель</label>
        <select class="model" name="">
          <option>Выберите модель</option>
          <option value="Модель 1" data-price="100">Модель 1</option>
          <option value="Модель 2" data-price="200">Модель 2</option>
          <option value="Модель 3" data-price="300">Модель 3</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form__item">
        <label for="">Количество</label>
        <input type="number" class="form__input values" value="1" min="1">
      </div>
      <div class="form__item">
         <div class="more-item">Добавить позицию</div>
      </div>
 </div>
  <div class="box">

  </div>
<!--  ==========================  -->

<!--  ==========================  -->
  <div class="form__submit">
    <div class="form__price price">
      Итого:
      <input type="text" class="price__input" value="0">
      руб.
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Вот это да. Учиться мне еще и учиться. Спасибо огромное!

Comment: Не вопрос, рад помочь